# Laravel path to image

Tags: image, file, upload, laravel

Image Move to folder using the tool move ()... 
But when I want to display it in html showing me the full path... 
for example on inspect elements show this: /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/uploads/
develop my app on localhost

```
$destinationPath = 'uploads/';
$filename = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind only the "public" directory is actually web accessible, so if you are moving something to anything not in "public", then it won't be web accessible. You can get around this by either a) moving it to somewhere in your 'public' directory, and then building a url to that (I suggest URL::to('/path/to/your/file')), or you can build a controller function which simply spits out your file.

I have done something similar in my app, with a controller that grants access (to authorized users only) to view uploaded content in a folder under app/userdocs:

```
// Read file then spit it out
$filepath = $doc->file;
$imagecontents = File::get(app_path().'/userdocs/' . $filepath);

if ($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg" || $ext == "png" || $ext == "gif")
{
    $contentType = "image/$ext";
}
else
{
    $contentType = "application/octet-stream";
}

return Response::make($imagecontents, 200, array('Content-Type' => $contentType));
```